Error 502 on Railway deployment with Docker and Nginx
I'm deploying Laravel to Railway using nginx and docker.
The deployment is almost successful, meaning it doesn't give any errors, but when I navigate to the URL, I get a 502 error in Railway's HTTP logs.
Any idea what might be happening?
vhost.conf :
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /build/ {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173/build/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /__vite_ping {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173/__vite_ping;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /@vite {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  app:
    container_name: laravel-app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=5432"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  web:
    container_name: laravel-web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - app

  database:
    container_name: laravel-database
    image: postgres:11.2
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/pgsql
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=mydb"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=myuser"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=expensecontrolpassword"
    ports:
        - "54321:5432"

  selenium:
    container_name: laravel-selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome

  adminer:
    container_name: laravel-adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

  node:
    image: node:18.19.1
    container_name: laravel_node
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    entrypoint: ["/var/www/entrypoint.sh"]
    ports:  
      -  "5173:5173"

volumes:
  dbdata: {}

app.dockerfile:
FROM php:8.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

web.dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.19.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

I checked the logs and I can't find any kind of information to know what's going on.

Can you share the full and exact error message?

Hi, Railway team member here:
Railway doesn't really support docker-compose as stated in the docs. However, there's a clean, fast and better way to deploy Laravel on Railway.
We have a comprehensive guide on it. https://docs.railway.app/guides/laravel
Please let me know if you need any help
